# Is there a C# function to get all stack elements as a joined string

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.1

I have a `Stack<string>` that I'm processing but sometimes I can't process all elements and would like to join/concatenate the remaining stack elements into one string. Is there an existing function or will I need to pop all elements in a loop and append them to a string variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1) function to concatenate a few objects into a single string.

Answer (score 3):

As the other posters mentioned, the solution is to use `String.Join()`

At least for a `Stack<string>` it seems it is not necessary to convert it `.ToArray()` or to `.ToList()`

```
var stack = new Stack<string>();
        
stack.Push("first element");
stack.Push("abc");
stack.Push("xyz");
stack.Push("last element");

var joinedString = String.Join(",", stack);

Console.WriteLine(joinedString); 
// will print: last element,xyz,abc,first element
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted any code sample of your stack implementation but `Stack<T>` has an `ToArray()` method which will return a `T[]` which in turn you can pass to `String.Join()` to get a joined string element.

Answer (score 1):

As [`System.Collections.Stack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack?view=netstandard-2.1) is `ICollection`, you can use all the Linq methods you want, like `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`.

After that, `string.Join()` to concatenate them.